# Как залогиниться сайт с помощью Get/Post запросов

Tags: c#

Нужно немного уточнить. Инфы нашел очень мало, поэтому спрошу. Вот например, нужно спарсить страницу сайта но сначала обязательно пройти авторизацию. И так, как получить html мне помогли понять. Вот код

```
 var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

    var dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    webResponse.Close();
```

Но, я не знаю как залогиниться пержде чем качать html. Говорили что нужно работать с cookiecontainer (не знаю что это). Я так понимаю нужно залогиниться, взять куки, потом их использовать. Но как пройти авторизацию. Можете дать пример кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно воспользоваться httpanalyzer и посмотреть что отправляется при попытке залогиниться, а уже от этого исходить, смотреть параметры запроса и формировать запрос на основе webRequest

Comment: Как все сложно то....

Comment: @Sergiy: Сложно потому, что это неподдерживаемый сценарий. Если у сайта есть API, пользуйтесь им. Если у сайта нет API, то он не хочет, чтобы с ним работали скрипты, и вы не должны этого делать.

Comment: @VladD вот как раз хотел спросить. Я хочу залогинится в Steam. Там есть API. Я не понимаю как все должно выглядеть. Для скачивания html я использую webrequest, для парсинга html agility pack. Но если использовать api, как можно получить\обработать данные.

Comment: Предварительно нужно получить api key, я думаю на сайте есть инструкцию по пользованию steam api, в том числе и мараметры формирования json-запросов

Comment: @Sergiy: Я никогда сам не работал с ним, но [вот вроде документация](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API). Надеюсь, поможет.